# Unable to preserve permissions when rsync'ing files owned by root:root to a macos

Tags: rsync

I have files on a linux server with ownership permission of root:root. When rsyncing to my local mac, these files change ownership permissions to root:wheel because there is no `root` group on a mac. I tried using the `--numeric-ids` option but that didn't help:

```
sudo rsync --rsync-path='sudo rsync' --numeric-ids -og me@host:/home/me/rsync_test/test_file.txt .
```

Comment: There is a root group on macOS. It's called `wheel`.

Comment: Right. And whee's gid is also 0. So I think I'm fine.